# Is using GLUT unprofessional?

Tags: opengl, glut

I read something from [here](http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl4/1-opengl-window.html) that said using GLUT is considered unprofessional. Swiftless has a fair amount of tutorials and I would consider him among NeHe as "go to OpenGL examples and tutorials". I have used GLUT in several languages in a few projects, though mostly for school projects. I find it very easy to make cross platform OpenGL apps with it.

Is using GLUT unprofessional? If so why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GLUT is no longer under active development, that's one reason not to use it.

Another is that other wrappers (GLFW, SDL) are not only under active development, but generally more powerful.

Also the callback-oriented API of GLUT is usually not considered very usable. I mean, it works and it is certainly possible to use it, but both GLFW and SDL want you to write the main loop of your program yourself (SDL also has platform-independent yet explicit message handling) which, at least in my opinion, results in MUCH more clear and flexible code.

My conclusion: using *some* platform independent wrapper for OpenGL is certainly better than, say, WinAPI, but GLUT is probably not the best choice among the wrappers which are available.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not unprofessional. Use whatever is easiest and fits your requirements. I find freeglut better then glut (different license, and provides better flexibility), but it should be fairly easy to switch from glut to qt or sdl.

Answer (score 0):

I can only argue for it being unprofessional on one point only: it may not be so portable to other platforms (such as Bada OS).

Comment: True, but they instead write Windows specific code which is even less portable.

Comment: Okay, then perhaps it is worth mentioning some cross platform SDKs for simplifying portability at the very least (eg. PowerVR SDK)